# GET request works with Postman but failed with 403 in python

Tags: python, python-requests, postman, http-headers, http-get

I tried to make a simple GET request to this url: https://www.artstation.com/projects/39L94v.json

I set same headers for both python and postman as below:

```json
{
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept-Language": "zh-CN,zh;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,ja;q=0.7",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)",
    "Host": "www.artstation.com"
}

//for those who wanna try in postman
accept:application/json
accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, br
accept-language:zh-CN,zh;q=0.9,ja;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
host:www.artstation.com
```

My python code failed with `<Response [403]>`:

```py
requests.get(url, headers=headers, proxies={'https': 'http://localhost:10809'})
```

Response text said "Access Denied" and `error code: 1020` which I find means firewall rules are violated.

I have tried adding, modifying and removing headers entries in python, but it didn't work.

While postman worked with same headers and proxy. Console log in postman:

```
GET https://www.artstation.com/projects/qe08KR.json      200  594 ms
Proxy
  href: "http://127.0.0.1:10809/"
Request Headers
  accept: application/json
  accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
  accept-language: zh-CN,zh;q=0.9,ja;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
  user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
  Host: www.artstation.com
Request Body
  Response Headers
  ...
```

I have no idea why this simple request behaves differently and python code doesn't work.

**UPDATE**:
Finally I found my python environment was broken somehow. After the reinstallation, problem was solved. Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The **User-Agent header must be set** in your request. Otherwise, the server responds with HTTP 403. You also should not send the Host header.

This works without error:

```
from requests import get as GET
HEADERS = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.4 Safari/605.1.15'
}
with GET('https://www.artstation.com/projects/39L94v.json', headers=HEADERS) as response:
    response.raise_for_status()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried this, but it still doesn't work. By the way, I need proxy in China to access the site. Maybe because of the proxy? But postman works. This is where I am confused.

Comment: If Postman works then Python program should as well. Check your proxy configuration in Postman. If needed, set the proxy in the Python as well, see https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#proxies.